# With setting up company email with Gmail, how do I administer the team account?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

About a month ago I set up the company email with Gmail for business.

I set up two accounts: one for myself which I am able to log into, and one for a teammate which I am not able to log into :)

How do I log into the admin console so I can administer my teammate's email?

I mean, what is the URL?

The company is problemio.

Comment: Should be asked on SuperUser. Flagging for migration.

Comment: @Itai: No, it shouldn't be on [su]. This would seem to be the most appropriate place.

Comment: @AlEverett Actually, I think that should have beeen [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "this". This _is_ web apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the Google Apps admin  login at http://google.com/a/yourdomain.com where you'd replace `yourdomain.com` with whatever domain you set up with Google.